# how to post body raw using mux and gorm in golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm, mux

I have problem with method post using gorilla/mux, and gorm, I want to request in body raw, but my code is error when I EXEC my procedure, why my code error? I'm still not understand to using request in body using gorilla/mux and gorm, how make post form using mux and gorm in golang?

My error is: [image]

```
    package main

    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
        _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "strconv"
        "time"
    )

    type SMSBlast struct {
        SequenceID   int `gorm:"column:SequenceID;PRIMARY_KEY"`
        MobilePhone string `gorm:"column:MobilePhone"`
        Output  string  `gorm:"column:Output"`
        WillBeSentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:WillBeSentDate"`
        SentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:SentDate"`
        Status *string `gorm:"column:Status"`
        DtmUpd time.Time `gorm:"column:DtmUpd"`
    }

    func (SMSBlast) TableName() string {
        return "SMSBlast2"
    }

func insertSMSBlast(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("New Insert Created")

    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS")
    if err != nil{
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    //sequenceid := vars["sequenceid"]
    mobilephone := vars["mobilephone"]
    output := vars["output"]
    willbesentdate := vars["willbesentdate"]
    sentdate := vars["sentdate"]
    status := vars["status"]

    var smsblats SMSBlast

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&smsblats)
    prindata := db.Debug().Raw("EXEC SMSBlast2Procedure ?, ?, ?, ? , ?", mobilephone, output, willbesentdate, sentdate, status).Scan(smsblats)
    fmt.Println(prindata)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&smsblats)

}
    func handleRequests(){
        myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
        myRouter.HandleFunc("/smsblaststestInsert", insertSMSBlast).Methods("POST")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",myRouter))

    }

    func main(){
        fmt.Println("SMSBLASTS ORM")
        handleRequests()
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are receiving.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I add my error picture

Comment: The error tells you the problem, the SP expects `@sentdate` and its not being provided. You need to double check the parameters you are passing and ensure you are passing all the required parameters with correct values.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have update my question , but now value I post from body get null value like this  EXEC SMSBlast2Procedure '', '', '', '' , ''  , I have update my question.

Comment: OK - thats not a database issue, so I'm un-tagging SQL. The issue is is obtaining the values from HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a lot of data to go off of here, but it seems like you're accessing the wrong values and getting blank strings in return.

```
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    mobilephone := vars["mobilephone"]
    output := vars["output"]
    willbesentdate := vars["willbesentdate"]
    sentdate := vars["sentdate"]
    status := vars["status"]
```

Gorilla would expect those all to be values present in the request path (`/{mobilephone}/{output}/{willbesentdate}`. I suspect that isn't the case since you also read in the request body into the struct.

Remove that part and don't use those values, use the values that are loaded into your struct.